# How can i make a struct keep the value ive assigned through the function?

Tags: c, struct, pass-by-reference, function-declaration

Basically I am trying to assign a value to a struct  through a function,so that the value that I've assigned is the same on main() afterwards.

The struct

```
struct member{
  char name;
  int age;
}m1;
```

```
void assigntostruct(struct member str,int age){

str.age = age;


main(){
int age=10;
assigntostruct(m1,age);
printf("%d",age);

}
```

I've tried it like this, the value "age" is passed to str.age, but then when I printf it returns 0.

Comment: You're missing at least a closing brace for `assigntostruct`.  Can you post code that at least compiles?

Comment: There is no need to pass `m1` to the function, since it is declared at global scope it is already accessible from `assigntostruct()`, just use `m1.age = age;` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an object of the structure type by reference.

In C the term passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it.

So the function can look like

```
void assigntostruct( struct member *str, int age){
    str->age = age;
    //...
}
```

and can be called like

```
assigntostruct( &m1, age );
printf("%d", m1.age);
```